# factbox no se muestra en la tabla - business central

Tags: tablas

Estoy tratando de ver un *factbox* en una tabla creada y no puedo verlo, si lo pongo como group lo puedo ver, pero si lo agrego como área no me muestra la otra tabla relacionada, son dos tablas (listPart y List), pero no puedo ver la relación:

```
page 50110 "RPM" 
{

    Caption = 'RPM';
    PageType = ListPart;
    SourceTable = "RPM";
    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(General)
            {
                field("No."; "No.")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                }
                field(Name; Name)
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                }
                field("RMP NO."; "RMP NO.")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Quiero agregar esa tabla en el área en la siguiente tabla:

```
page 50100 "RMP MASTER"
{

    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {

            repeater(General)
            {
                
                field("No."; "No.")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = Basic;
                }
        
            }

        }

        area(FactBoxes)
        {

            part(RPM; "RPM")
            {
                ApplicationArea = Basic;
                SubPageLink = "RMP NO." = field("No.");
            }

        }


    }

}
```

No puedo ver la información al agregarlo como área, pero sí puedo verla
al agregarla como group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la page `50100` no figura el `pageType` ni el `sourceTable`. Intenta agregar estos datos y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: gracias Jonathan!